# Conditional probability with exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm having big problems with this exercise. Help would be appreciated.

> The life of a repairing device is $\mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$- distributed. Peter wishes to use it on $n$ different, independent, $\mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac{1}{na}\right)$- distributed occasions. Compute the probability that this is possible.

I'm not even completely sure what I'm supposed to compute. One idea I had was that if $N$ is the time using the device and $T$ is the life of the device, then I want to solve

$$P(N < t | T = t) = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\frac{P(N=t, T=t)}{P(T=t)}.$$
As I said, that might be completely wrong.

Anyway, trying to solve the sum above gives me the wrong answer. The answer should be $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n.$

Comment: Clearly the answer doesn't depend on $a$ (it's just linear time-scaling), so set $an=1$. Then the probability you are looking for is [$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x}}{(n-1)!}e^{-x/n}\,dx$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Comment: Here is an integral free way: probability that the repair device will outlive the first repair occasion is $\frac n {n+1}$. Conditional on that, due to memorylessness probability of outliving the second repair occasion is the same. Hence the answer is $(\frac n{n+1})^n\to e^{-1}$.

Comment: @A.S. But how do you get that the first occasion is $\frac{n}{n+1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @A.S., if $X$ is the life of the device and $Y_n$ the time of the $n^{\mathsf{th}}$ occasion then
$$\mathbb P(X>Y_1) = \frac{na}{a+na}=\frac n{n+1}. $$
(Here I am assuming that "$\mathsf{Exp}\left(\frac1a\right)$-distributed" means "exponentially distributed with mean $\frac1a$".)

By independence and the memoryless property it follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X>Y_n) &= \mathbb P\left(X>Y_n\mid \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \{X>Y_i\}\right)\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \{X>Y_i\}\right)\\
&=\mathbb P(X>Y_n)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathbb P(X>Y_i)\\
&= \left(\frac n{n+1}\right)\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^{n-1}\\
&= \left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n.
\end{align}

Comment: How do we get the first line though? That's the most difficult part for me